# Expo app icon not being properly displayed

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I recently created an expo application. When I generated an apk for android and tested it on my device, the app icon looks zoomed in and fitted properly. I used the recommended icon size 1024x1024px I also tried 512x512px but still got the same thing

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App",
    "slug": "app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
    "primaryColor": "#3399ff",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue - leaving out the android.adaptiveIcon key in app.json fixed the issue for us, but this post might have a better solution https://blog.tgxn.net/expo-adaptive-app-icon/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how to create icons for expo first.
There are two ways to do so, first you use one single image e.g. icon.png, if this is your case, this should be your app.json file in a expo project

```js
{
"expo": {
  "icon": "./assets/icon.png"
  }
}
```

If you have a small PNG Cutout of your Logo with Transparent Background and you want to have that as an icon, then you can add that type of logo as well and here you have the option to add a background color for the icon as well
check that out here : https://docs.expo.dev/guides/app-icons/